# 'Failed to mount component' error for 'vue-table-2' component in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

I'm new in here and also Vue.js.

I want to try 'vue-table-2' like here; (https://jsfiddle.net/matfish2/jfa5t4sm/) but I couldn't run it correctly.

"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap3": "^3.3.5",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.21",
    "vue-tables-2": "^1.4.70"
},

console error message;

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <VueClientServer>
       <HelloWorld> at src/components/HelloWorld.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

my code;

```
<template>    
  <div>    
    <h3 class="vue-title">Vue Tables 2 Demo - Client Component</h3>    
    <div id="users">    
<vue-client-server :columns="columns" :data="data" :options="options">
        <a slot="uri" slot-scope="props" target="_blank" :href="props.row.uri" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></a>
        <div slot="child_row" slot-scope="props">
          The link to {{props.row.name}} is <a :href="props.row.uri">{{props.row.uri}}</a>
        </div>
      </vue-client-server>
    </div>
    <p class="vue-pagination-ad">
      Like the pagination component and want to use it independently? Try <a target="_blank" href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pagination-2">vue-pagination-2</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
   import VueClientServer from "vue-tables-2";
  // import {ServerTable, ClientTable, Event} from 'vue-tables-2';
  export default {
    name: "HelloWorld",
    props: {
    },
    components: {
      VueClientServer
   },
    data() {
      return {
        columns: ['name', 'code', 'uri'],
        options: {
          headings: {
            name: 'Country Name',
            code: 'Country Code',
            uri: 'View Record'
          },
          sortable: ['name', 'code'],
          filterable: ['name', 'code']
        },
        data:[{
              code: "ZW",
              name: "Zimbabwe",
              created_at: "2015-04-24T01:46:50.459583",
              updated_at: "2015-04-24T01:46:50.459593",
              uri: "http://api.lobbyfacts.eu/api/1/country/245",
              id: 245
          }],
        }
      },
  };
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
```

Comment: Have you tried searching "template or render function not defined" on the web? What did that show you? If you are still stuck, how do these other references not apply?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for answer. Of course I search it, but I couldn't do integrated the 'Rollup' and 'webpack' sides from here;
https://vues.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only

This is my first Vue.js project:

Comment: Make sure you [edit] the question with the steps you have taken to research and solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exposing jquery, axios, moment, bootstrap & daterangepicker globally?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2#date-columns

You can do this in main.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
window.axios = axios
```